# Error al retornar False or true Java

Tags: java

Tengo un error de lógica que me esta dando dolores de cabeza, requiero de hacer un sistema de `login`, los campos son quemados, pero necesito pasarlo a un método, cuando lo ejecuto no me devuelve ni `true` ni `false`, y al ejecutarlo como un método no realiza la cuenta de los **tres intentos**.

¿Cómo podría mejorarlo?

```
public class Login1 {

    public static boolean login(boolean login) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cont;
        boolean salir = false;
       String user[] = {"Usuario1", "Usuario2", "Usuario3"};
        String usuario, contra;
        String pass[] = {"uno1", "Dos2", "tRes3"};

        System.out.println("Ingrese su usuario y contraseña para iniciar");

        while (!salir) {
            for (int i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
                int contInt = 1;
                int a = i;
                System.out.println("\033[30mIntento " + (a + 1));
                System.out.println("Digite su usuario: ");
                usuario = teclado.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Digite su contraseña: ");
                contra = teclado.nextLine();
                if (usuario.equals(user[0]) && (contra.equals(pass[0])) || usuario.equals(user[1]) && (contra.equals(pass[1])) || usuario.equals(user[2]) && (contra.equals(pass[2]))) {

                    System.out.println("Bienvenido al sistema");
                    login=true;


                    salir = true;
                    //contInt++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.println("\033[31m***********************************");
                    System.out.println("\033[31m* USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA *");
                    System.out.println("\033[31m***********************************");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    if (i == 2) {
                        System.err.println("HA CUMPLIDO CON LA CANTIDAD DE INTENTOS PERMITIDOS.");
                        System.err.println("SISTEMA BLOQUEADO, ESPERE... ");
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10000); // espera en milisegundos
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            login=false;
                        }

                    }
                    salir = false;

                }

            }
        }//fin wh
        return login;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean iniciar = true;
        Login1.login(iniciar);
        System.out.println(login(iniciar));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio, bienvenido a SOes, Su método login más tiene pinta para ser un main de su clase Login1, le invito a realzar  [el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento del sitio con respecto a su pregunta, no veo la utilidad de pasar un valor booleano y retornar ese valor nuevamente.

Comment: Buenas entiendo, estare revisando el tour, debo de generar el metodo login para indicarlo en otra clase, por eso requeria acomodar que si me daba un true iniciara el resto de los procesos, o un false para cerrar la aplicacion. De eso mi consulta.  Agradezco la aclaracion.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentaba, no veo la utilidad de pasar un valor `booleano` a una función y retornar ese valor nuevamente. *(a menos que se me esté pasando algún detalle)*

Si usa indice fijos como *(user[0]* para especificar la posición de un array *(0)*, no tiene caso tener un `for` que itere sobre el array de elementos.

Para tener e iterar sobre los elementos y en el caso que desee añadir más usuarios y contraseñas, deberá utilizar el `for` y acceder al elemento a validar tanto en el array de usuarios como en el de contraseñas, haciendo uso del indice `i`, además tener una nueva variable `booleana`  *(login)* , para manejar cuando se debe salir del ciclo `for` .

```
public static void login() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir =  false;
    login=false;
    String user[] = {"Usuario1", "Usuario2", "Usuario3","admin"};
    String usuario, contra; 
    String pass[] = {"uno1", "Dos2", "tRes3","admin"};
    int contInt =1;
    while (!salir) {
            System.out.println("\033[30mIntento " + contInt);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su usuario y contraseña para iniciar");
            System.out.println("Digite su usuario: ");
            usuario = teclado.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite su contraseña: ");
            contra = teclado.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < user.length && !login; i++) { //mientras no haya login
            if (usuario.equals(user[i]) && (contra.equals(pass[i]))) {
                // cuando coincidan los valores, se corta el ciclo for
                // mediante la variable booleana login 
                login= true; 
            }
        }
        if(login){ // Si se ingresaron los datos correctos
           System.out.println("Bienvenido al sistema"); 
           salir = true; //salimos del while
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("\033[31m***********************************");
            System.out.println("\033[31m* USUARIO O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA *");
            System.out.println("\033[31m***********************************");
            System.out.println(" ");
            if (contInt == 3) {
                System.err.println("HA CUMPLIDO CON LA CANTIDAD DE INTENTOS PERMITIDOS.");
                System.err.println("SISTEMA BLOQUEADO, ESPERE... ");
                System.out.println(" ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // espera 10 segundos, en milisegundos
                    contInt=1; //reseteamos el contador de intentos

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }             
            contInt ++; //añadimos el contador de intentos
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/QuaintMagentaCoins)</kbd>

Comment: En este caso ocupaba retornar un valor para: en caso de que el login fuera valido (Usuario y contraseña), enviara un true para iniciar la aplicacion como tal, si fuera un false, que siguiera intentando hasta cumplir los tres intentos y que bloqueara el sistema por un momento. Como ves, para eso ocupaba retornar esos valores, estoy comenzando en esto, por eso hay ciertos errores de logica aun presentes, Agradezco las observaciones.

Comment: @MauricioMejias Si, sería los más lógico retornar una variable booleana pero el  proceso sería totalmente diferente. Espero le ayude mi respuesta. Saludos